# How to retrieve file id from table and pass it to modal in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog

In my project I have a table which lists all the files uploaded by user with options to view or delete them. When the user clicks delete it opens a modal which asks for confirmation. Everything works fine except that when I click delete in any other file except the first file the modal always asks for confirmation to delete the first file. In short only the first file in the table gets deleted. I cannot retrieve the ID of other files, to pass it to deleteentry/{id}.

Here is the code with modal (myModal):

```
<tbody class="searchable">
                @foreach ($files as $entry)
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $entry->original_filename }}</b></td>
                        <td><b>{{ $entry->created_at }}</b></td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route('getentry', [$entry->filename]) }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">View</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            <!-- Modal HTML -->
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:IndianRed;">Confirmation</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                                            <p>Do you want to delete the file {{ $entry->original_filename }} </a>permanently?</p>
                                            <p class="text-primary" style="margin-top:-40px;"><small>If you click yes, the file will be deleted from our database permanently.</small></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:-40px;">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                            <a href="{{ route('deleteentry', [$entry->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" style="width:90px;" data-toggle="modal">Yes</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

It works when I remove the modal altogether and have just:

```
<tbody class="searchable">
                @foreach ($files as $entry)
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $entry->original_filename }}</b></td>
                        <td><b>{{ $entry->created_at }}</b></td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route('getentry', [$entry->filename]) }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">View</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ route('deleteentry', [$entry->id]) }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

So it shows that the problem lies with the modal but I cant figure out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same value for the `id` attribute for all your confirmation modals, which is not allowed. So to avoid that you'll need to add some additional piece of data to the `id` attribute for each item. The easiest way to ensure they are unique is by appending `$entry->id` to each one like so:

```
<tbody class="searchable">
    @foreach ($files as $entry)
        <tr>
            <td><b>{{ $entry->original_filename }}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{ $entry->created_at }}</b></td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('getentry', [$entry->filename]) }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">View</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger">Delete</a>
                <!-- Modal HTML -->
                <div id="deleteModal_{{ $entry->id }}" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:IndianRed;">Confirmation</h4>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                                <p>Do you want to delete the file {{ $entry->original_filename }} </a>permanently?</p>
                                <p class="text-primary" style="margin-top:-40px;"><small>If you click yes, the file will be deleted from our database permanently.</small></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top:-40px;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                <a href="{{ route('deleteentry', [$entry->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" style="width:90px;" data-toggle="modal">Yes</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```